# Will Migration Assistant affect other MacBook user(s)?

Tags: macos, user-account, migration

The MacBook in question has two user profiles (both administrators) with separate Apple IDs, separate workflows etc. (i.e., unrelated or loosely related to each other); one of the profiles is my own. If I use Migration Assistant to restore settings (appearance, mostly) for my own profile, can/will that destructively affect (override, erase, hide) that other profile or some information in it?

Please, also note that the other person is not a power user, so if some info or UI element becomes hidden (rather than lost), this is also something that I'd like to know about.

Comment: You cannot Migrate into an existing user so how are you planning to do this?

Comment: Ohh, I should've known that before adding new user profile on a shared machine (and looks like [I'm not alone in this](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/windows-migration-assistant-for-existing-user-account-on-mac.2323850/))